# The React.js route in the component must call other components depending on the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am starting to learn react and trying to implement it in my old project. The problem is as follows.

**Have App.js with Rows**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Bets from './components/bets/bets';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/bets" component={Bets}/>
        <Route exact path="/bets/live" component={Bets}/>
        <Route exact path="/bets/ended" component={Bets}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Routes call **Bets.js** The contents of **Bets.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

import BetsLive from './bets_live';
import BetsEnded from './bets_ended';
import BetsUpcoming from './bets_upcoming';

const Bets = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="row container">
            <NavLink to="/bets">
                Upcomming
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/bets/live">
                Live
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/bets/ended">
                Results
            </NavLink>

            // здесь

        </div>
    );
}

export default Bets;
```

Where **"// here"** should be a specific component depending on the URL. examples below

```
/bets  =  <BetsUpcoming/>
/bets/ended  =  <BetsEnded/>
/bets/live = <BetsLive/>
```

How to solve this problem? There is an idea to do it through props (pass some kind of parameter in Route), and do a return through verification (*heap of code*  *heap of code*)

Answer (score 0):

Add `BetsLive`, `BetsEnded` and  `BetsUpcoming` in routes:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Bets /> { /* use NavLink to make link to specific routes. */ }
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/bets" component={BetsUpcoming}/>
            <Route exact path="/bets/live" component={BetsLive}/>
            <Route exact path="/bets/ended" component={BetsEnded}/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Also you can use Switch and Route to nest routes, check example in [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look more in the [React Router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

As i am correctly understand, you need to realize a simple ToDo list router with moving to corresponding component according the clicking button. Then you should put corresponding component in the corresponding route:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Bets from './bets';
import BetsLive from './bets_live';
import BetsEnded from './bets_ended';
import BetsUpcoming from './bets_upcoming';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Bets />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/bets" component={Bets}/>
        <Route exact path="/bets/live" component={BetsUpcoming}/>
        <Route exact path="/bets/ended" component={BetsEnded}/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
   );
}
```

And in the `Bets` component realized the movement on the routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Bets = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="row container">
            <NavLink to="/bets">
                Upcomming
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/bets/live">
                Live
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/bets/ended">
                Results
            </NavLink>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Bets;
```

The key moment is that you should pass *component* in `component` prop of the `<Route />`, *which* you want to see in the corresponding path.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with route parameter (kinda of props as you mentioned):

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Bets from './components/bets/bets';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/bets/:whatbets" component={Bets}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

import BetsLive from './bets_live';
import BetsEnded from './bets_ended';
import BetsUpcoming from './bets_upcoming';

const Bets = (props) => {
    const {whatbets} = useParams()

    return (
        <div className="row container">
            <NavLink to="/bets">
                Upcomming
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/bets/live">
                Live
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/bets/ended">
                Results
            </NavLink>

       {whatbets === 'live' && <Live />}
       {whatbets === 'ended' && <Ended />}
       {!whatbets && <WithoutParams />}


        </div>
    );
}

export default Bets;
```